# Rails 4 Cookie Issues - Chopped Values and Interference with Other Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 issue regarding cookies that has been giving me a headache all day, with no solution. The cookie value changes, or seems to affect the value of other variables. I am new to Rails and programming in general, and I suspect I am mis-using the cookie, but it sure would be nice for this to work.

The app has a deck of cards, makes a small pile, and selects a card from that pile. The card selection is where the errors occur.

All code is in application_controller.rb. I am storing the cookie[:pile] Array of card_ids as a string, and array-arizing it when I need it.

This code works:

```
  def select_card_id
    @pile = cookies[:pile].split(',')
    i = rand(@pile.length - 1)
    @id = @pile[i]
  end
```

Voila. A random card from the pile each time.

If I want to cycle through the cards in a less random order, the app has to know which card to pull next, and that's where the cookies fail.

This code fails with an error of "undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass", meaning the @pile variable.

```
  def select_card_id
    @pile = cookies[:pile].split(',')
    i = cookies[:index]

    if i < @pile.length
      @id = @pile[i]
      cookies[:index] += 1
    else
      cookies[:index] = 0
      @id = @pile[0]
    end
  end
```

The plot thickens, as I force cookies[:index] to an integer, which is twice weird because I set it to 0 earlier and it wasn't the source of the error, but the app simmers down about @pile being nil.

This code fails with an error of "Couldn't find Card with id=3"

```
 def select_card_id
    @pile = cookies[:pile].split(',')
    i = cookies[:index].to_i

    if i < @pile.length
      @id = @pile[i]
      cookies[:index] = i + 1
    else
      cookies[:index] = 0
      @id = @pile[0]
    end
  end
```

The code it is referring to is this, in the 'new' action of the 'test' controller:

```
@id = select_card_id
@card = Card.find(@id)
```

What's weird about that is not only is there no card_id of 3, or even of one digit, but after a lot of trial and error I realized that the cookie was cutting off the first digit of the variable.  The @id selected in this instance wasn't 3, it was 33.  When @id is 40, it looks for 0.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: i think you are assuming that you can store integers in cookies, but you can only store strings. please post the code that sets the index.

Comment: The code that sets the index is already up there, but it sets it to an integer, so that's probably the issue. Any recommendations for dealing with that? Should I convert integers to strings to store, then reconvert to integers to use, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: the int to string is implicit, you need to string to int when dealing with the cookie value

Comment: string to int was already added (see example above), but once I added int to string before saving, the value was saved correctly and the issue was resolved. Thank you! If you put your first comment as an answer I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies store strings. Any kind of type conversion needs to be done by the application code.